# Accordion List in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface, accordion

Does windows phone have a 'accordion list' control? If not what else can one do to achieve the same look and experience of a expandable list?

I've been googling around and it seems like there's no straight answer to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using the ExpanderView control from the Microsoft Windows Phone toolkit which is free.

May be you just have to style it a little so that it looks like an Accordion List.

You can use the control in a simple way, by populating it with Items:

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView Header="Expander Header" x:Name="expander">
    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
        <TextBlock FontSize="40" Text="Expanded Content"/>
    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
</toolkit:ExpanderView>
```

Or you can use Data Binding.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of 3rd party quality custom controls built for WP7. Try to download WinPhone DevHub and Telerik Examples from the Marketplace, I am pretty sure you will find what you want already implemented.
Telerik controls are not free, but WinPhone DevHub has a lot of free controls. You will find details on where to download them also in the app.

Comment: thanks for your input. Do you perhaps have a link to these examples? I can't seem to find the right page...

Comment: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/35571846-14bc-4db2-bc58-2d592763da12 and http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx